# Excel VBA: What is the best way to sum a column in a dataset with variable amounts of lines?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to sum two columns (B and C) in a dataset. The number of rows with data will vary between 1 and 17. I need to add the sums two rows beneath the last row of data (end result example in image 1).

My code worked beautifully for one dataset, but I am getting an error

> Run-time error'6': Overflow

for a different dataset. What am I doing wrong?

```vb
    'Units total
    Windows("Final_Files.xlsb").Activate
    Sheets("Revenue Summary").Select
    lastrow = Worksheets("Revenue Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim a As Integer
    a = 10000

    For i = lastrow To 2 Step by - 1
        a = a + Worksheets("Revenue Summary").Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next

    Worksheets("Revenue Summary").Cells(lastrow + 2, 2).Value = a
```

Correct End Result
[image: Image 1 - Correct End Result]

Comment: Don't use `Integer`, or `Long` either. And don't loop to sum... use `WorksheetFunction.Sum`.

Comment: There is a bug in the code. In `.Cells(Rows.Count, 2)` the call to `Rows` assumes `ActiveSheet`. Replace the above with `.Cells(Worksheets("Revenue Summary").Rows.Count, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code summs up all the rows under "B2" and "C2". Adapt it to your needs.

```
' Keep a reference to the worksheet
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Revenue Summary") 

' This is how many rows there are. 
Dim rowCount as Long     
rowCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row-1

' This is the summation operation over each column
Dim b as Double, c as Double
b = WorksheerFunction.Sum(ws.Range("B2").Resize(rowCount,1))
c = WorksheerFunction.Sum(ws.Range("C2").Resize(rowCount,1))

' This writes the sum two cells under the last row.
ws.Range("B2").Cells(rowCount+2,1).Value = b
ws.Range("C2").Cells(rowCount+2,1).Value = c
```

Comment: OP didn't tell us if the totals in his picture may already exist. If they do, they will be included in the sum drawn by your function.

Comment: Hi John, 
Thank you for this suggestion. The issue is that the data set will always vary and I need something that will sum column b and column c no matter what the size of the data set is when it is run. Thanks though!

Comment: Then you need to measure the empty cells first and replace the 100 with the number of rows. Something like `.Resize(rowCount, 2)`. See edits to answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below sub-

```
Sub SumBC()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lRowB As Long, lRowC As Long
Dim bSum As Double, cSum As Double
    
    Windows("Final_Files.xlsb").Activate
    Set sh = Worksheets("Revenue Summary")
    lRowB = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lRowC = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    bSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(sh.Range("B2:B" & lRowB))
    cSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(sh.Range("C2:C" & lRowC))
    
    sh.Cells(lRowB + 2, 2) = bSum
    sh.Cells(lRowC + 2, 3) = cSum

sh.Activate
Set sh = Nothing
End Sub
```

> ***Remember:*** If you want to run same sub multiple time then you need clear totals otherwise it will add totals again again below of last totals.

Comment: Hi Harun24HR,
This almost works! The issue now is that there is only one total - the total in column C. For some reason the total in column B is not entered. Why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect but there is only one error. You have initialized variable 'a' with 10000. Change it to 0.

a = 0

then your code will be perfect.

Comment: Yes, I tried that at first, but it did not work. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

### Add Totals to Multiple Columns

- **If you're not OP**: It is easy to test the code. Open a new workbook and insert a module. Copy the code into the module. Uncomment the `Sheet1` line, and outcomment the `Revenue Summary` line. In worksheet `Sheet1` add some numbers in columns 2 and 3 and your ready.
- Run only the `insertTotals` procedure. The `calculateSumOfRange` is called when needed.
- Play with the constants in `insertTotals` and change the values in the columns. Add text, error values, booleans to see how the code doesn't break.
- The issue with `Application.Sum` or `WorksheetFunction.Sum` is that it fails when there are error values in the range. That's what the `calculateSumOfRange` is preventing. If there is an error value, the loop approach is used. If not, then `Application.Sum` is the result.
- You can use the `calculateSumOfRange` in Excel as a UDF. Just don't include the cell where the formula is and you're OK, e.g. `=calculateSumOfRange(A1:B10)`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertTotals()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2 ' First Row of Data
    Const LastRowCol As Long = 2 ' The column where the Last Row is calculated.
    Const TotalsOffset As Long = 2 ' 2 means: 'data - one empty row - totals'
    Dim Cols As Variant
    Cols = Array(2, 3) ' add more
    
    'With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With Workbooks("Final_Files.xlsb").Worksheets("Revenue Summary")
        ' Define Last Row ('LastRow') in Last Row Column ('LastRowCol').
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Define Last Row Column Range ('rng').
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, LastRowCol), _
                         .Cells(LastRow, LastRowCol))
        Dim j As Long
        ' Validate Columns Array ('Cols').
        If LBound(Cols) <= UBound(Cols) Then
            ' Iterate columns in Columns Array.
            For j = LBound(Cols) To UBound(Cols)
                ' Use 'Offset' to define the current Column Range and write
                ' its calculated total below it.
                .Cells(LastRow + TotalsOffset, Cols(j)).Value = _
                  calculateSumOfRange(rng.Offset(, Cols(j) - LastRowCol))
            Next j
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Function calculateSumOfRange(SourceRange As Range) _
         As Double
    
    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName As String = "calculateSumOfRange"
    On Error GoTo clearError ' Turn on error trapping.

    ' Validate Source Range.
    If SourceRange Is Nothing Then
        GoTo NoRange
    End If
    
    ' Calculate Sum of Range.
    Dim CurrentValue As Variant
    CurrentValue = Application.Sum(SourceRange)
    Dim Result As Double
    If Not IsError(CurrentValue) Then
        Result = CurrentValue
    Else
        Dim Data As Variant
        If SourceRange.Rows.Count > 1 Or SourceRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then
            Data = SourceRange.Value
        Else
            ReDim Data(1, 1)
            Data(1, 1) = SourceRange.Value
        End If
        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
                CurrentValue = Data(i, j)
                If IsNumeric(CurrentValue) And _
                  Not VarType(CurrentValue) = vbBoolean Then
                    Result = Result + CurrentValue
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
    
    ' Write result and exit.
    calculateSumOfRange = Result
    GoTo ProcExit

' Labels
NoRange:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': No range (Nothing)."
    GoTo ProcExit
    
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
    GoTo ProcExit

ProcExit:

End Function
```

Comment: Hi VBasic2008,
Wow! This is wonderful. Thank you so much!